# Any reason I should join ResearchGate?

Tags: soft-question

I am getting "invitations" to join ResearchGate. I am not a member of any other social network, as I consider it a waste of time. Are there good reasons for a mathematician to join ResearchGate? Can anybody provide experiences that speak for or against joining?

Comment: I wonder the same. I am quite annoyed by them, since they "poison" the google search results and adds more clicks before reaching the actual article. So, based on this, I do not support them. They make my work harder, not easier. I wonder if they provide say bibtex info to articles, since this is something I would find useful.

Comment: MathSciNet already provides bibtex info, in case you didn't already know that.

Comment: There is extensive discussion of ResearchGate on academia.se, for example [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/researchgate-an-asset-or-a-waste-of-time).  The general impression is strongly negative.

Comment: @KetilTveiten, MathSciNet is good, but not everyone has access to it, especially from home. Google Scholar is free and provides BibTeX info, but the quality is not always that good.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Of course, that's a good point.

Comment: Do you like getting lots of useless email you will never read?  Then ResearchGate is for you.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Another source for BibTeX info is [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/). I find it far more preferable than MathSciNet, since it's open-access, and also more than Google, due to style. Concerning ResearchGate, I was annoyed that I was tricked into signing up by being led to believe that I could download some paper I couldn't find anywhere else; after having signed up, there was no downloadable paper at all. It somehow, stupidly, didn't occur to me that such cheap marketing could be targeted at academia... ResearchGate is mostly about spam in my experience.

Comment: To me, ResearchGate seems to be mainly a source of SPAM -- for example
I got again and again messages like the following, asking me to confirm
authorship of papers on subjects like entomology or ornithology,
written in languages I don't speak:
*"Aleš Dolný invited you to join their network on ResearchGate and confirm authorship
of your publications. Stefan Kohl 1 Publication - 1 Citation
Určovací klíč exuvií evropských druhů vážek (Odonata) podřádu Anisoptera"*
(Once I googled and emailed the purported inviter, asking whether
he really meant to send me that message, but never got a reply.)

Comment: I agree that ResearchGate is mainly spam. I joined it because I got an invitation from someone I respect, but I almost don't check their mails.

Comment: I voted to close since this is better asked on acdemia.SE (where indeed it already got discussed at length) as it is not only not about mathematics but not even  specifically for mathematics or mathematicians.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) there is a question [ResearchGate: an asset or a waste of time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/researchgate-an-asset-or-a-waste-of-time).

Opinions there are mostly negative (not only not too beneficial, but also can annoy others [e.g. distinguished professors with whom you are collaborating] with emails). E.g.:

> As is, I have yet to hear any positive success story from my peers. All I've heard of ResearchGate are complaints about their invitation spam.

or

> My experience with ResearchGate has been negative. I was searching for a paper online, and a ResearchGate page came up. I signed up as a member because they promised to send me a pdf of the paper. They never sent it and instead sent unrelated spam.

That said, as with any social network, it can change over time.

Personally, I would love to have a *good* profile/networking site for scientists, but it seems that we need to wait.

Or as put by one comment on A.SE:

> My personal stance is that RG is a wonderful idea (especially the Q&A parts) which are terribly executed.

Comment: I ran into some programming bug from them and similar from LinkedIn. I was getting copies of the invitations to anyone in the building; part of that was a local IT problem, but in the end I just filtered everything to trash without appearing in my mail queue. Later, I realized I joined both because of invitations I thought were personal but were probably not.

Comment: Perspective check: companies that everyone complains about the rude (and/or illegal!) invite spam tend to be big and growing and well-used. See LinkedIn, unroll.me tc.

Comment: @djechlin It's called growth hacking. Sometimes efficient, but once overdone in can backfire. Indeed, RG got a lot of users. But "I have yet to hear any positive success story from my peers". For LinkedIn I know a lot of success stories.